# How to simulate iOS app crashing in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is there a way to simulate an app crashing? Purpose being I want to check that data is gracefully saved & retained if somehow app randomly crashes on an actual user device.

Comment: Divide by zero is my usual choice.

Comment: Why was this closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can press Stop when running in debug mode..

Comment: Is there a "applicationWill..." function called in that case?

Answer (score 10):

Ooh, there is a lot of ways crashing your app)
For example, index out of range exception:

```
NSArray *array = @[];
array[1];
```

Or in short form:

```
@[][1];
```

Comment: Does that kind of coding error result in the same kind of crash as if the app just randomly crashed on a user? You know, the kind that happens even if nothing is wrong with the actual app code, like device ran too many progs at once, ran out of memory, or something on the device was faulty?

Comment: It depends on what do you need to check in the case of crash. For example, if application crashes due to the lack of memory, behaviour somehow differs from the crash when something with your code is wrong(i.e. unsupported API method call).

Comment: Apps often crash for no reason. Take your favorite bug-free app and run it 1000 times. It will crash at least once, for no obvious reason. That's the kind of crash I need to check.

Answer (score 2):

Do it programmatically in your code.

Xcode have any button like "Hey dude crash my app" ^^

NSInvalidArgumentException :

```
NSMutableArray *tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSObject *object = nil;
[tmp addObject:object];
```

Comment: Details seems somewhat lacking...

Comment: This is more like a comment.

Comment: True jedys can do crashes even without thinking about it :)

Answer (score 1):

In old non ARC code you could try to cast -1 to (NSObject*)
(which is disallowed in ARC code, iOS 4.3 and above) and then try to take class of it.

```
[(NSObject*)-1 class]; // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Similar to this you can try to do it in modern:
The old good force casting evil.

```
Swift: 
var nilObj: Array? = nil 
nilObj!
```

Obj-C:

Clean and safe approach is to use assert, this will only crash in debug build

```
NSAssert(1==0, @"Always crashing assert")
```

Alternatively you could try to make Exception. This will work on both debug and release build.

```
[NSException raise:@"Exception", format: @"Reason"];
```

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. It looks like a correct answer, so to avoid accidental deletion could you add a few words explaining what the code does or what EXC_BAD_ACCESS is?